# If multiple words overlap, they will not be toggled properly

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I created a keyword toggle button using CSS and Javascript.

◆ WORD Toggle button Javascript

```
var DIVS = document.querySelectorAll(`.ClapLv2ListItem_Chie-ListItem__Anchor__347mo, .ListSearchResults_listSearchResults__listItem__F0427, 
.ClapLv2QARankingItem_Chie-QARankingItem__Anchor__2S_YM`);

var WORDS = [
    'Safari', 'Macintosh', 'iPhone',
];


//----- Set default state -----//

window.addEventListener('load', l => {
    for (let i = 0; i < DIVS.length; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < WORDS.length; j++) {
            if (DIVS[i].innerHTML.match(WORDS[j])) {

                DIVS[i].style.zoom = 0.4;
                DIVS[i].style.marginLeft = '30px';
                DIVS[i].style.backgroundColor = '#f5f5f5';

            }
        }
    }


    //----- Insert HTML (toggle button generation) -----//
    let sort_label =
        document.querySelector("#sort > div.ClapLv2Sort_Chie-Sort__Select__anKwT > div > label");
    sort_label.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', `
    <div class="sample_switch" id="makeImg">
      <input type="checkbox" id="toggle_check" checked=""/>
        <label for="toggle_check" onclick="Toggle_Switch()" >
          <span></span>
        </label>
    </div>
    `);
});


//----- Switching processing setting when the toggle button is pressed -----//

function Toggle_Switch() {
    for (let i = 0; i < DIVS.length; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < WORDS.length; j++) {
            if (DIVS[i].innerHTML.match(WORDS[j])) {
                if (DIVS[i].style.display == "none") {

                    DIVS[i].style.display = "block";
                } else {

                    DIVS[i].style.display = "none";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

◆ WORD Toggle button CSS

```
.sample_switch {
    zoom: 70%;
    left: 0.5px;
    bottom: 230px;

    position: fixed;
}


.sample_switch input[type = "checkbox"] {
        display: none;
    }


    .sample_switch label {
        display: block;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        text-align: center;
        border: 2px solid #ccc;
        border-radius: 3px;

        height: 50px;
        line-height: 50px;

        font-weight: bold;
        width: 45px;
        font-size: 22px;

        background: #eee;
        box-shadow: 3px 3px 6px #888;   
      transition     : .3s;               
    
    cursor: pointer;
    }
     
    
    .sample_switch label span:after{
      content        : "CL";    /*"close"*/
      color          : #aaa;

    }
    .sample_switch #toggle_check: checked + label {
        background: #78bd78;        
    /*  box-shadow     : none;  */       
    }
    .sample_switch # toggle_check: checked + label span: after {
                content: "OP"; /*"OPEN"*/
                color: #fff;
            }


            .sample_switch: active {
                height: 48px;
                margin-top: -2px;
                transition: none;
            }
```

I chose the keyword because I thought it was easy to explain, not in such an environment. There is no other meaning.

Switch the gray element with the green button on the left.
For DELL's Chrome browser, it is designed to fit the page by setting the zoom factor to 150%.

As a result of trying to switch keywords, in the case of a single word, it was switched normally.

The problem is that if the specified words overlap, it doesn't seem to be toggled properly.

For example, if the target element contains a single `iPhone`, you can switch between them.

But,

`iPhone` + `Safari` etc.
If the element contains multiple specified words, it cannot be switched.

Target page ( Japan's largest Q&A site )

https://chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/category/2080401334/question/list?sort=16

https://chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/category/2080401478/question/list?sort=16

https://chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/category/2080401523/question/list?sort=16

I'd like to fix an issue where multiple words don't toggle properly when they overlap, what should I do?

please tell me.